# PI Server not completing php code with 1000 SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi Model B+, which means it has 512MB memory. I'm trying to update an SQL database on my Pi with PHP and I'm copying over transactions from a third party via their API. It's also a LEMP server setup if that makes a difference.

The issue is the page when run updates transactions (1,900) but the page doesn't load, i.e. show the summary information, I simply get a blank page.

I admit this is the initial stage and the code should not have to update more than 100 transactions at a time after the initial copying of old transaction to my Pi but I'm curious as to what the issue is exactly and how to manage it.

The code works fine with a couple of accounts where there are only a few hundred transactions per account. The code finishes and shows a few lines of info of how many accounts updated and how many transactions.

The code doesn't finish when it gets to an account with nearly 2,000 transactions.

Things noticed:

1. Initially just running the code on the one account the code updated 500 transactions and then stopped/crashed etc.
2. Increasing the www.conf max_children setting from 5 to 15 (even tried 50) the code now updates all 2,000 transactions but the code doesn't finish, meaning the page doesn't show summary information, no header (which contains buttons etc.), just a blank screen.
3. I've tried adding a set_time_limit to the php code but doesn't seem to do much.
4. had a look in the php, mysql etc. error logs in the /var/log/messages directory and nothing is in the logs apart from standard events.

I'm happy to accept the limitations of my Pi but would love to learn why it's failing and how to manage it.

Haven't put the code as there's a lot but the logic is as below but let me know what you would like to see:

1. Retrieve all transactions from 3rd party API and store in array.
2. Process array into a new array that only contains the needed data, formatting and editing certain fields.
3. Cycle through the array and insert it into the SQL database via a prepared statement. (I briefly saw there sql transactions but not
   looked into it)
4. Count the number of accounts updated and number of transactions.
5. Print summary information.

Comment: Your logic seems long winded, why fetch data, process 1, insert data.  Just fetch each transaction and (using prepared statements as you are) insert the processed data.  No need to build it in memory, just pass it through.

Comment: @marc  Turn on with  SET GLOBAL general_log=1;  run your process, look at the tail of the log to see what has been used.  1st run for count of 5 that does summarize.  Then run it for 1000 and look at the new tail of the general log.  Consider a SLEEP nn seconds before expecting the Summary to work and display.  Just a WAG.

Comment: Thanks both! I tried and no luck. I did go through the error logs again and noticed a "upstream timed out (110: connection timed out)". By setting and increasing the fastcgi_read_timeout to 900 my website has come back to life showing all summary data, albeit still a php time out error but that I can manage that. Useful link for [Increasing PHP Execution Time](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/php/increase-script-execution-time/)